# Анимация в three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, gsap

Недавно начал изучать three js и столкнулся с такой проблемой, как анимирование 3д объектов.
Коротко говоря, мне нужно, чтобы 3д объекты одновременно меняли позицию и opacity. Пытался сделать через gsap. Мой код: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgn3avkx/1/

Пробовал `tl.staggerFrom([meshesPosition,meshesMaterial], 0.08, {z: -5, opacity: 0}, 0.006)`
, но получалась "дискотека" =)

Comment: Чтобы менять прозрачность отдельно взятого куба, нужно чтобы и материал был для него отдельный. Сейчас используется единый общий материал для всех кубов.

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с tween.js (с GSAP знаком не очень хорошо; [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/dqegtw30/)):

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
//renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// 10 x 10 tiling
var squares = [];
var geom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry();

for (let y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {

    let mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: "black",
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    })
    mat.userData.colorFrom = new THREE.Color("black");
    mat.userData.colorTo = new THREE.Color(Math.random() * 0xffffff);

    let s = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);

    s.position.set(
      x + 0.5 - 5,
      y + 0.5 - 5, -5
    );
    s.rotation.x = -Math.PI;

    let counter = y * 10 + x;

    s.userData.tween = new TWEEN.Tween({
        val: 0
      })
      .to({
        val: 1
      }, 3000)
      .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.Out)
      .delay(25 * counter)
      .onUpdate(v => {
        s.position.z = THREE.MathUtils.lerp(-5, 0, v);
        s.rotation.x = THREE.MathUtils.lerp(-Math.PI, 0, v);
        mat.color.copy(mat.userData.colorFrom).lerp(mat.userData.colorTo, v);
      });
    squares.push(s);
    scene.add(s);
  }
}

squares.forEach(s => {
  s.userData.tween.start();
})


renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  TWEEN.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/16.0.0/Tween.min.js"></script>
```